# difference between detach and interactive mode

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

If I run the container in detached mode, it works as expected as shown below. But if I run it in interactive mode, port 9200 is not assigned to elasticsearch as expected.

```
# docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node"  -d elasticsearch:7.3.1
650a7ec48812325631183d1c9d53e7d6d81ab296bfe9d8076593471aede4fa43

# docker exec -it 650a7ec48812325631183d1c9d53e7d6d81ab296bfe9d8076593471aede4fa43 bash

[root@650a7ec48812 elasticsearch]# curl http://localhost:9200/
{
  "name" : "650a7ec48812",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "soPITNmpTimq7KJApj9s9A",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.3.1",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "4749ba6",
    "build_date" : "2019-08-19T20:19:25.651794Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.1.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

As per my understanding detach and interactive/ terminal modes are same (one continues in the same thread while other creates a new). Can someone explain the difference between these 2 modes of running docker image?

```
# docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" -it elasticsearch:7.3.1 bash

# curl http://localhost:9200/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to ::1: Cannot assign requested address
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is because `elasticsearch` is not started since you overwrite the `CMD` the container will run to `bash` that has nothing to do between modes...

Comment: Can I start elastic and still use interactive mode?

Comment: not sure try something like `runuser -l elasticsearch -c "./bin/elasticsearch -d -p pid"`since you can not start it as a root